# Künneth spectral sequence for cohomology of chain complexes of $R$-modules

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital ring.  Let $\mathbf{A}_\bullet$ and $\mathbf{C}_\bullet$ be positive chain complexes of $R$-modules.  If $\mathbf{A}_\bullet$ consists of flat $R$-modules then there is *homology Künneth spectral sequence*
$$E^2_{p,q}:=\bigoplus_{s+t=q}\mathrm{Tor}_p^R(H_s(\mathbf{A}_\bullet),H_t(\mathbf{C}_\bullet))\Rightarrow H_{p+q}(\mathbf{A}_\bullet\otimes_R\mathbf{C}_\bullet).$$

I am interested in a cohomological version, specifically, is the following true?

> Suppose $\mathbf{C}_\bullet$ is a negative complex.  If $\mathbf{A}_\bullet$ consists of projective $R$-modules, then there is a *cohomology Künneth spectral sequence*
> $$E^2_{p,q}:=\bigoplus_{s+t=q}\mathrm{Ext}^p_R(H_s(\mathbf{A}_\bullet),H_t(\mathbf{C}_\bullet))\Rightarrow H_{p+q}(\mathrm{Hom}_R(\mathbf{A}_\bullet,\mathbf{C}_\bullet)).$$

A version of this appears in Rotman's introduction to homological algebra (first edition) but it does not appear in the second edition and I do not know of another reference.

If the "theorem" is true, what is a reference for it?

Comment: Are you sure you have the degrees right?

Comment: Possibly not, what do you think they should be?

Comment: This could be found in [EKMM](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/EKMM.pdf) Thm 4.6 (or Lurie's Higher Algebra).

Comment: I didn't actually think through what I would expect the degrees to be, but as a rule of thumb homological and cohomological degrees are minus each other. And Ext and Hom are contravariant in the first entry. So the $(p,s,t)$ summand on the LHS looks to me like it is in total homological degree $-p-s+t$, not $p+s+t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of the hyper(co)homology spectral sequence from Chapter XVII, Section 2 of Cartan-Eilenberg (1953), for the functor $T(C,A) = \mathrm{Hom}_R(A,C)$.  The $E_2$-term is given in equation (4) on page 368, essentially as
$$
E_2^{p,q} = \prod_{s+t=q} \mathrm{Ext}^p_R(H_s(\mathbf{A}_\bullet), H^t(\mathbf{C}^\bullet))
\Longrightarrow H^{p+q}(\mathrm{Hom}_R(\mathbf{A}_\bullet, \mathbf{C}^\bullet)) \,,
$$
with $p$ as the filtration degree.